# How to pass wrong value as argument in I18n using rails validates inclusion validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-i18n

I want to validate inclusion in `country_code` field in my `Country` table.
And I want to show specific error for the invalid record using **I18n**.

My model:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  validates :country_code,
        inclusion: { in: ISO3166::Country.codes, allow_blank: true, message: I18n.t('models.country.invalid_country_code', value: value) }

end
```

My localisation:

```
de:
  models:
    country:
      invalid_country_code: "%{value} is invalid"
```

But I see `NameError: undefined local variable or method "value" for #<Class:0x00007f8e5de83dc8>` error message in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution: putting **value** in quotes with % fix this problem.

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  validates :country_code,
    inclusion: { in: ISO3166::Country.codes, allow_blank: true, message: I18n.t('models.country.invalid_country_code', value: '%{value}') }

end
```